# How to show that $\psi(x)=-A\exp(-\alpha^2x^2)$ satisfies TISE for $V(x)=\frac 1 2 m\omega_0^2x^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

I'm struggling to approach this 'show that' question:

> Write down the time-independent Schrödinger differential equation for $\psi(x)$ in a one-dimensional and time-independent potential $V(x)$. In the case that $V(x)=\frac 1 2 m\omega_0^2x^2$, show that at large values of $x$, $\psi(x)=A\exp(-\alpha^2x^2)$ is a solution to this differential equation, where $\alpha$ and $A$ are constants.

I've tried substituting $\psi$ into the TISE, but (to my untrained eye) this didn't offer up any evidence that $\psi$ is a solution.

I would be grateful if someone might suggest an approach, not a complete solution.

Comment: It will be great if you can show your work, and it will be more evident to see in which step you had gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the TISE as
$$\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}=\frac{m^2\omega_0^2x^2-2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi$$
and observe that for large $x$, $2mE$ is negligible compared to $m^2\omega_0^2 x^2$.

Therefore, you can write it as
$$\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}=\frac{m^2\omega_0^2x^2}{\hbar^2}\psi$$
Now prove that the function $\psi(x)=Ae^{-\alpha^2x^2}$ satisfies this equation. First, you should differentiate $\psi(x)$ twice to get to the left side of the equation, and discard some terms that are negligible when $x$ is very large. Then, insert the $\psi(x)$ to the right side and some common terms should cancel out. You should also be able to find the value of $\alpha$.

If you still can't solve the problem using these suggestions, tell me in the comments and I'll post further advices.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'd say it's a valid suggestion as the question indicates to "show that at large values of $x$..."

Comment: @nuwe you’re right.  Why didn’t I see this?  I will delete my comment.

Comment: @User123. This college HW question brings no value to this website (thought of as a knowledge database), so we generally discourage providing answers. The HW policy has exceptions, but this Q is none of them.

Comment: @User123 Thank you so much for your help - it's really appreciated. So I have (and I don't know if maths text will work in the comments section but here it is) $4A\alpha^4x^2-2A\alpha^2=\frac{m^2\omega_0^2x^2}{\hbar^2}$. I could see how, in limit where x is large, this equivalence sort of holds - am I on the right track?

Comment: @NGodrich That's it, you are on the right track. You just forgot $A$ on the right side. Try to apply a limit $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @User123 I mean, I can see how  $4A\alpha^4x^2$ could become just $x^2$ and how $-2A\alpha^2$ will be come negligible, or zero. And sure, $\frac{m^2\omega_0^2x^2}{\hbar^2}$ could also be equivalent to just $x^2$ in the limit, yielding $x=x$... is this what I'm looking for? This doesn't feel very satisfactory.

Comment: @NGodrich I agree, $-2A\alpha^2$ is negligible. Therefore, you are left with $4A\alpha^4x^2=A\frac{m^2\omega_0^2x^2}{\hbar^2}x^2$ (you forgot $A$ on the right side again). Cancelling some terms, $\alpha^4=\frac{m^2\omega_0^2}{\hbar^2}$, or $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega_0}{\hbar}}$. Therefore, we have showed that $\psi(x)$ satisfies TISE, and we have even found for which $\alpha$ is this the case. Because $A$ cancells out, $\psi(x)$ satisfies TISE for every $A$.